# Aurelia Js select box not working

Tags: jquery-plugins, aurelia

Am new to Aurelia Js , here, am using a simple select box but its not working while changing the value.

**HTML :**

```
<select value.bind="selectVal" change.delegate="changed()">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Doc.Type</option>
                        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
                    </select>
```

**Model :** 
   `this.selectVal = '';
changed(){
        alert();
    }`
 **change.delegate** is not triggering while change the value. Also, datepicker value is not loading in the model. What will be the issue? Is it any from my end or form Aurelia js issue.

Comment: You can use jquery selectors only on `attached(){...}` event of you component (after DOM rendering).

Comment: @JayDi  sorry, what you mean jquery selectors ? like $('#xx').val() ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Like: $('#dateStart').datetimepicker({locale: 'ru',format: 'DD.MM.YYYY'});

Comment: @JayDi  $('.datepicker').pickadate({selectMonths: true, selectYears: 15 });
        $('select').material_select();  already done this.

Comment: @sibi Can you please clarify if you're actually using jQuery/Materialize in this case? I'm a little confused because your original post doesn't mention any of these. :-)

If you DO use Materialize, the case here will be that its select doesn't fire a change event. You would have to capture that and fire a CustomEvent.

It works like in this gist:
https://gist.run/?id=4e7dd11228407e765844570409d210bd

Comment: @Daniel yes,am using Materialize with jQuery dependency.

Comment: Have you tried the gist? The solution might be in there.. ;-)

Comment: @sibi I've tried to answer this below, please have a look. :-)

Comment: some what its working, am getting error in console 'Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded' , i found that its looping multiple times when i put 'console.log()' next to this line 'this.option.dispatchEvent(customEvent);'

Comment: Ah right.. I've wrapped this with a `_suspendUpdate`. I'll add this info to my answer below. You can write code more easily in answers. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Materialize (as became apparent from the comments of the original questions) the select element won't fire any `change` event. You would have to listen to the jQuery `change` event and fire a `CustomEvent` in the event handler.

Like this:

```
_suspendUpdate = false;
attached() {
  $(this.option).material_select()
  $(this.option).on('change', e => {
    if (!this._suspendUpdate) {
      let customEvent = new CustomEvent('change', {});
      this._suspendUpdate = true;
      this.option.dispatchEvent(customEvent);
      this._suspendUpdate = false;
    }
  });
}
```

Note: the `suspendUpdate` "trick" is needed because a `change` CustomEvent also causes jQuery to fire its own `change` event which causes an infinite loop.

The view template for the snippet above:

```
<template>
  <require from="materialize/dist/css/materialize.css"></require>
  <div class="input-field col s12">
   <select ref="option" value.bind="optionSelect">
     <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
     <option value="1">Option 1</option>
     <option value="2">Option 2</option>
     <option value="3">Option 3</option>
   </select>
   <p>Selected value: ${optionSelect}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is also a gist.run which demonstrates this approach:
https://gist.run/?id=4e7dd11228407e765844570409d210bd

Of course if you're using Materialize with Aurelia, you can also use the Materialize bridge: http://aurelia-ui-toolkits.github.io/demo-materialize/#/about

Disclaimer: I'm one of the creators of Aurelia Materialize bridge.

Comment: Hi daniel, i tried your code, it throws a console error that 'app.js:8 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded' . i need to trigger a function, on change.

Comment: Updated. I'm not sure if the `this` inside the jQuery `change` handler actually works because jQuery reassigns it.. If that is the case you would need to assign `this` to another var and use that inside the handler.

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis sorry,done.check out and y not upvote mine ... lol